# How to make pre-initialized array contents work, vs. array.push()?

Tags: javascript

Why can't the images be defined in an array as shown here.
Why is it necessary push a new Image object in the array every time?

```
var canvas = null; 
var ctx = null; 
var assets = [
    '/media/img/gamedev/robowalk/robowalk00.png', 
    '/media/img/gamedev/robowalk/robowalk01.png', 
    '/media/img/gamedev/robowalk/robowalk02.png', 
    '/media/img/gamedev/robowalk/robowalk03.png', 
    '/media/img/gamedev/robowalk/robowalk04.png', 
    '/media/img/gamedev/robowalk/robowalk05.png', 
    '/media/img/gamedev/robowalk/robowalk06.png', 
    '/media/img/gamedev/robowalk/robowalk07.png', 
    '/media/img/gamedev/robowalk/robowalk08.png', 
    '/media/img/gamedev/robowalk/robowalk09.png', 
    '/media/img/gamedev/robowalk/robowalk10.png', 
    '/media/img/gamedev/robowalk/robowalk11.png',
    '/media/img/gamedev/robowalk/robowalk12.png', 
    '/media/img/gamedev/robowalk/robowalk13.png', 
    '/media/img/gamedev/robowalk/robowalk14.png', 
    '/media/img/gamedev/robowalk/robowalk15.png',
    '/media/img/gamedev/robowalk/robowalk16.png',
    '/media/img/gamedev/robowalk/robowalk17.png', 
    '/media/img/gamedev/robowalk/robowalk18.png' 
];

var frames = [];  
var onImageLoad = function() { 
    console.log("IMAGE!!!"); 
};
var setup = function() { 
    j=0; 
    body = document.getElementById('body'); 
    canvas = document.createElement('canvas');  
    ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');  
    canvas.width = 100; 
    canvas.height = 100;  
    body.appendChild(canvas); 
    for (i = 0; i <= assets.length - 1; ++i) {     
       frames[i].src = assets[i]; 
    } 
    setInterval(animate,30);
}

var animate = function() { 
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height); 
    if (j >= assets.length) { 
      j=0; 
    } 
    var image = new Image(); 
    image.src = frames[j]; 
    ctx.drawImage(image,0,0);
    ++j;  
}
```

Comment: Please edit your question and use the formatting tools! And please given an explanation of what you're trying to do and what result you're getting instead.

Comment: no meaning. try to explain

Comment: Everything about your question was sloppy, confusing, hard to read, understand and people are voting it down quickly. It's about to be closed. I *may* have saved it, by editing your code. Next time you post, please click the (?) in the editor window and learn how to use markdown language to format your code neatly into a block. Don't post your whole question in the title, make the title a summary and post a clear question in the text area. If you don't put some effort into respecting the way the forum works and making your questions clear/readable you won't have success getting good answers.

Comment: ok thanks i will take your advice seriously

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first reason is to reduce latency. Putting only the URLs into an array means that images have not been pre-fetched before the animation starts. The first round of animation is going to be slow and jerky as each image is retrieved from the net. If the animation is repeated, the next round will be faster. *This consideration mostly applies to animations which replaced image elements on the page (in the DOM) rather than by writing to a canvas.*

The second reason is to remove overhead and improve efficiency in the animation loop. Using `new Image()` inside the loop means that drawing time for each frame includes the time taken to create a new Image object as well as draw it on the canvas. *In addition* the image content can only be written to the canvas after it has been fetched, making it necessary to write to the canvas from an `onload` handler attached to the image object. The posted code does not do this and could throw an error in some browsers trying to synchronously write an image with no data to the canvas. Even if otherwise successful, repeated animations would be creating a new Image object each time a frame is displayed and churning memory usage.

Note the original version probably used `onImageLoad` to check when the image has been fully loaded from the web before pushing the object into an array of preloaded image objects. This is the preferred method of prefetching animation images.

And don't forget to define `j` before use :-)

Comment: Sir is this code correct my intention was to write a flipbook animation

Comment: PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Linux 0.0.0) frames Each frame should have a 'src' attribute of '/\/media\/img\/gamedev\/robowalk/' FAILED
 expected undefined to match /\/media\/img\/gamedev\/robowalk/
PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Linux 0.0.0) animate first parameter of ctx.drawImage call should be one of our frames FAILED
 expected drawImage to have been called with arguments Udacity Rocks
     drawImage(<img src="Udacity Rocks"></img>, 0, 0)
     drawImage(<img src="/media/img/gamedev/robowalk/robowalk00.png"></img>, 0, 0)

Comment: I've updated the answer to say that synchronously drawing an image immediately after setting it's `src` attribute will cause problems. Other than than answering the question posted I have nothing to add - I  don't understand why you might create an animation in a headless browser and can't help further.